# Why the property "Window.Left" doesn't change when you move the window

Tags: wpf

I want to move a window with a storyboard. But after the storyboard completed, if you move the window with mouse, the property "Window.Left" doesn't change when you move the window. I can set "FillBehavior=FillBehavior.Stop" to solve this problem, but I don't know why.

```
 public void MoveWindow()
        {
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
            DoubleAnimation xAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            Storyboard.SetTarget(xAnimation, this);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(xAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Window.Left)"));
            xAnimation.From = this.Left;
            xAnimation.To = this.Left + 100;
            xAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2);
            storyboard.Children.Add(xAnimation);
            storyboard.Begin();
        }

  private void btn_Move_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MoveWindow();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `FillBehavior.Stop` to ensure that the animation does not hold the property value.

From the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks) in the online documentation:

> Set an animations FillBehavior property to HoldEnd when you want the animation to hold its value after it reaches the end of its active period. An animation that has reached the end of its active period that has a FillBehavior setting of HoldEnd is said to be in its fill period. When you don't want an animation to hold its value after it reaches the end of its active period, set its FillBehavior property to Stop.

Add a `Completed` event handler to set the current property after the animation has run.

```
public void MoveWindow()
{
    var xAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        To = Left + 100,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2),
        FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop
    };

    xAnimation.Completed += (s, e) => Left += 100;

    BeginAnimation(LeftProperty, xAnimation);
}
```